# How to get the text from the textarea in IE6?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, textarea

If I use textarea.value then I get an error, so I tried to use textarea.innerHTML, but it returns with an empty string...

So how to get the textarea text in IE6?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have test on [IETESTER](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), it's ok.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loaded(){
        var area = document.getElementById("area");
        alert(area.innerHTML);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loaded()">
   <textarea id="area"> some text innerHTML</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found the solution. I have to write elem.innerHTML = ''; instead of elem.value = '';

Answer (score 1):

> If I use textarea.value then I get an error

That's weird, I don't.

Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zdu8f/

Also IE6? In 2012? Seriously?

Every millisecond that you spend today in regress testing your application in a newer browser so that you can get rid of IE6 is hours of development time that you will win tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Danny, have you tried using jQuery? It will make it easy for you to do such things the same way across the browsers. Here a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zdu8f/

Answer (score 1):

Am not getting any error using .value in ie6 see

http://jsfiddle.net/kunalvashist/3GR7h/